# Trouble with using Freemarker to formate Date for GeoServer GetFeatureInfo

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo, date, datetime

I'm having some trouble while trying to use the Freemarker Template to display dates in the desired format.

I store points with a date information in a PostGIS database written through an FME-process in an ISO format (%Y-%m-%d) to use them in an time-enabled WMS with GeoServer.

When calling the GetFeatureInfo, the date is displayed in the following format 10/4/12 12:00 AM, where it should be 2012-10-04. We allready changened the server setting to `-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true -Duser.country=DE -Duser.timezone=GMT -Duser.language=de.`

Since this didn't give the desired outcome, we tried it with the Freemarker Template. The idea was to check the attributes for date format and format them accordingly. Somehow, I can't make it work. I tried this:

```
<#if attribute.is_unknown_date_like>
${attribute.value?string("YYYY-MM-DD")}
<#else>
${attribute.value}
</#if>
```

I get an error message for the line where the condition starts:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException
```

How can I make this condition statement work?

Edit 01.07.2020:

I realized that I should use `attribute?is_data_like` with a `?` since it is a build-in. With this change, the error message gets more significant.

```
2020-07-01 08:19:02,521 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -  freemarker.core.ParseException: Error on line 29, column 46, in template content.ftl Found is_date_like, expecting one of:  is_directive,  parent,  js_string,  j_string,  uncap_first,  is_transform,  number,  is_hash,  trim,  children,  has_content,   iso_ms,  xml,  iso_utc,  byte,  double,  left_pad,  matches,  capitalize,  number_to_datetime,   contains,  size,  iso_local_h_nz,  iso_utc_ms,  iso_local_m_nz,  is_collection,  long,  default,  iso_utc_h_nz,  iso_local_ms,  is_boolean,  last_index_of,  c,  iso_utc_m_nz,   is_macro,  rtf,  iso_utc_nz,  upper_case,  node_name,  reverse,  cap_first,  url,  is_hash_ex,   iso_nz,  is_enumerable,  exists,  number_to_date,  first,  iso_local,  date,  iso,  replace,  float,   right_pad,  datetime,  node_type,  split,  iso_ms_nz,  number_to_time,  is_sequence,  iso_utc_m,  html,   ancestors,  iso_utc_h,  iso_local_ms_nz,  new,  last,  sort,  eval,  lower_case,  web_safe,  is_date,   is_string,  iso_local_nz,  word_list,  seq_last_index_of,  node_namespace,  string,  keys,  iso_m_nz,  values,   seq_index_of,  chunk,  sort_by,  iso_m,  starts_with,  substring,  index_of,  iso_h,  root,  floor,  iso_h_nz,   ceiling,  if_exists,  chop_linebreak,  iso_local_h,  length,  is_indexable,  groups,  is_node,  iso_local_m,  int,   iso_utc_ms_nz,  xhtml,  ends_with,  round,  interpret,  is_method,  namespace,  short,  seq_contains,  time,   is_number  in content.ftl
```

So, the problem seems to lie within the built-in. As statet in the error message, Freemarker expects `is_date` instead of `is_date_like`, eventhough in the Freemarker documentation it is stated that `is_date_like` should be uses instead of `is_date` https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html.

So I tried the following:

```
<#if attribute.value?is_date>
${attribute.value?date?string.iso}
<#else>
${attribute.value}
</#if>
```

Now, no error message appears, but the date format is unchanged.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please use the [edit] button to update your question with the whole exception message

Answer (score 1):

From the [free marker documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html) it looks as if `atribute.value?date` should do it but I lack a suitable datey dataset to test on right now.

Comment: Thank you for your Help. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I still get an error message. I think the problem lies within the condition and the condition statement. I fear I haven't been precisely enough in my Question. I will edit it.